# Why was the number $73.2$ used in "Sharper bounds for the Chebyshev functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$. II" in theorem 10, inequality 6.2?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, chebyshev-function

In Schoenfeld's paper "Sharper bounds for the Chebyshev functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$. II," theorem 10, inequality (6.2) states "If the Riemann hypothesis holds, then $|\psi(x) - x| < \frac{1}{8\pi}\sqrt{x}\ln^2{x}$ if $x > 73.2.$ However, it is true for $59 < x \le 73.2$. Why was the number $73.2$ used?

Comment: It doesn't matter too much, but it might be useful for convenience. When I saw this statement with the specific number $73.2$, I thought that $73$ violated the inequality, but it didn't.

Comment: My first guess is (considering the paper you're referencing is from the 70's), that maybe the lower of the lower bounds wasn't found until more recently.

Comment: @PrincessEev The paper states "On using Gram's table again, we verify (6.17) for $73.2 \le x < 1075.$" If it was checked over such a huge range, it should be trivial to check from $41$ to $73.2.$

Comment: I'm finding violations of the inequality up to just less than $x=59$ instead of $41$ (see equation (6.4) as well). Of course the modified question still remains.

Comment: @GregMartin So , the claim that $73.2$ can be replaced by $41$ is wrong ?

Comment: In case anyone wonders. the first comment by the OP above was in reply to a comment of mine - which has mysteriously disappeared. It asked "Why does it matter?" The point of the comment was to elicit further context.